# Mapear resultados de una promesa y mandar respuesta del mapeo

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promesas

Yo tengo mi base de datos en MongoDB, y dentro de cada documento tengo un valor *is_active* de valor booleana, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que si es que el valor es true, me lo regrese como respuesta al frontend.

Si hago el console.log, si me lo da bien y me devuelve solo los que tengan *is active: true*, pero si le hago, *res.send(restaurantes)* me manda un JSON vacío.

Traté de poner en res.send afuera del mapeo pero no me regresa nada, se va al catch

```js
 restauranModel.find().exec()
        .then(resp => {
            resp.map(data => {
                var active = data.is_active
                var restaurantes = []
                if (active) {
                    restaurantes.push(data)
                }
                console.log(restaurantes)

            })
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(409).send(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo logré solucionar con un filter, al final el código quedo de la siguiente manera

```js
restauranModel.find().exec()
        .then(resp => {
            let datos = resp.filter((data) => {
                return data.is_active === true
            })
            res.send(datos)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(409).send(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

Como lo has conseguido es correcto, aunque es más optimo si filtras en la `query`, de esa forma Mongoose te devuelve el dato ya filtrado y evitarías tener que hacer el `filter`, ahorrando tiempo y recurso de la maquina:

```
restauranModel.find({ is_active : true }).exec()
        .then(resp => res.send(resp))
        .catch(err => res.status(409).send(err))
```